# How to equalize a variable of a node of a linked list to char variable in c?

Tags: c, file, pointers, variables, linked-list

I am programming a simple text editor in c. I defined a structure named node and created a linked list named textbuffer. I am trying to create an insert function for the text editor. The function takers line and stat parameters. I want to equalize statement variable of a node of textbuffer list but it gives me an error. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    char statement[40];
    int next;
};
struct node textbuffer[25];

int free_head;
int inuse_head;

void insert(int line, char* stat)
{
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("deneme.txt","w");
    
    if(file!=NULL)
    {
        
        
        
        textbuffer[line].statement=stat;
        
    
    }
    
    else
    {
        printf("File couldn't found.");
    }
    fclose(file);




}
```

it gives me this error:

error: assignment to expression with array type
23 |   textbuffer[line].statement=stat;

How can i solve this?

Comment: Use strcpy( textbuffer[line].statement, stat ); provided that stat is a pointer to a string with the length less than 40. You will need to include the header <string.h>

Comment: I think trying to assign char* to char[40] is not well defined operation. There are good functions that does this things for you, for example the one in comment above or a better version for my oppinion: strncpy(textbuffer[line].statement, stat, 40), that will copy a maximum of 40 characters to your buffer